# Development in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

At my organization, I'm working on a cloud based application that delivers information to sales team in the Dynamics CRM. It's required to build a UI in Dynamics CRM or integrate a UI with Dynamics.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone link me to any good resources on the matter or provide me with any information you feel would be relevant? I've been doing a lot of research but haven't found anything about how to develop in Dynamics (programming languages, development framework for both UI (native vs HTML/hybrid) and backend changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is a little unclear as to what exactly you are trying to achieve; but assuming that you want a custom UI to be visible from within CRM then I would recommend:

1. Developing your UI as standalone web application or set of web services and HTML resources
2. Hosting the UI within CRM as an external iFrame or CRM Webresource

Hosting an iFrame within CRM: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328034.aspx

Using CRM Webservice to access CRM:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx